# Web Scraping using python -How to interact with the object in the webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

How to expand the list(+) from the web page and get the title and timings? I'm new to web scraping,so kindly guide me.

```or-tag-here
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.simplilearn.com/big-data-and-analytics/big-data-hadoop-architect-masters-program-training")
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Selenium, It's very easy. You just have to first find the xpath for the expand button. Below is the example for expanding 'Big-Data and Hadoop Developer' column on the given page.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body_content"]/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div[1]/span')
elem.click()
```

Comment: But still i'm unable to get the title / timing information. `elem.click() 
html = driver.page_source 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml") 
print soup.findAll("ul",{'class':'course-preview-accord bundle-course-preview course_preview_15 ng-isolate-scope'}) `

Comment: Hey you can use selenium's method "find_elements_by_xpath" to get list of items in that list.

Comment: Yes, I did the same. But there is no li list in page source .Output: `[<ul acc-arrow-down="expand" acc-arrow-up="collapse" acc-levels="2" acc-status="1" class="course-preview-accord bundle-course-preview course_preview_15 ng-isolate-scope" compile-acc="pc.accConstructCheck" compile-check="pc.startAcc" dir-multi-accordion="" multi-acc-level="1">\n<!-- ngRepeat: cpObj in pc.coursePreviewData -->\n</ul>]
'